# Download random item from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, random, firebase, firebase-storage

I have 1000 items in Storage uploaded by users and I want to download a random one. What's the best approach?

I could name them with 1 - 1000 names, but there could be more than one user uploading at the same time.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest save all the filenames (preferably randomly generated or firebase key based) in a database node...

From here you can get this whole node, then get the length,
generate a random number, then mod this random number to the length;

Get the nth child where n = randomNumber%length

Comment: Thanks, but each user will be uploading files at the same time. So each user will have to update that node and add the uploaded file name to it. How can I manage users acessing the same node at the same time?